# how to displayed each pair of items in a new line?

Tags: javascript

How can I display each pair of items in a new line...

For Example :

1 | nishant | 18 | noob in everthing

2 | mayank | 18 | python king

3 | kartik | 18 | python hero

I tried, but it shows each pair of items in a single line if I am using  `const infoList = info.map(singleinfo=> <h1>{singleinfo.id} | {singleinfo.name} | {singleinfo.age} | {singleinfo.skill}</h1>)` its works fine but I need to know how it can be done by using template literals

**Code:**

```
import React from 'react'
function NameList() {
    const info = [
        {
            id:1,
            name:'nishant',
            age:18,
            skill:'noob in everthing'
        },
        {
            id:2,
            name:'mayank',
            age:18,
            skill: 'python king'
        },
        {
            id:3,
            name:'kartik',
            age:18,
            skill: 'python hero'
        }
    ]
const infoList = info.map(singleinfo=> `${singleinfo.id} | ${singleinfo.name} | ${singleinfo.age} | ${singleinfo.skill}`) 

return (
        <div>
            <h1>{infoList}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}


export default NameList
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply adding a new class say `addlinebreak` with `white-space: pre-line` style and will also need to add `\n` in the end of each template literal inside `.map()` method like:

```js
const info = [{id:1,name:"nishant",age:18,skill:"noob in everthing"},{id:2,name:"mayank",age:18,skill:"python king"},{id:3,name:"kartik",age:18,skill:"python hero"}];
const infoList = info.map(singleinfo=> `${singleinfo.id} | ${singleinfo.name} | ${singleinfo.age} | ${singleinfo.skill}\n`)

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="addlinebreak"><h1>{infoList}</h1></div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.addlinebreak { white-space: pre-line; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: If we use ```.addlinebreak { white-space: pre-line; } ``` then why we need to add ```\n``` at the end of each template literal?

Comment: That is needed to specify to the browser to wrap the text at that point only, else it will only do the normal wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Your `infoList` variable is just pure text without any HTML in it.

Try adding a `<br/>` tag to the end of it instead.

```
const infoList = info.map(singleinfo=> `${singleinfo.id} | ${singleinfo.name} | ${singleinfo.age} | ${singleinfo.skill} <br/>`) 

return (
        <div>
            <h1>{infoList}</h1>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: I tried but it's just simple print </br> at the end of each pair of items

Answer (score 0):

You might want to wrap each value from the map function with the `<h1>` tag, here's the complete code of what it looks like

```
function NameList() {
    const info = [
        {
            id:1,
            name:'nishant',
            age:18,
            skill:'noob in everthing'
        },
        {
            id:2,
            name:'mayank',
            age:18,
            skill: 'python king'
        },
        {
            id:3,
            name:'kartik',
            age:18,
            skill: 'python hero'
        }
    ]
    const infoList = info.map(singleinfo => <h1>{singleinfo.id} | {singleinfo.name} |
        {singleinfo.age} | {singleinfo.skill}</h1>)

return (
        <div>
            {infoList}
        </div>
    )
}


export default NameList
```